# Static maps API that serves roads/labels without basemap?

Tags: layers, mapbox, api

I am looking for a static maps API (similar to https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/ ) that can serve the map without an underlying base layer. My intention is to generate images with the roads/labels layer on top of a custom base layer. 
Does such a thing exist? If not, what can I use to create it?

Comment: Is there a particular area you're looking at?

Comment: You can create your own google map styled map then request the style in static form https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Comment: @Branco the whole world, but particularly the continental united states

Comment: I guess you could create something with node and [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/), similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/30374742/1504487

Answer (score 3):

Using the **Google Static Maps API**

Try:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=london&size=1080x720&sensor=false&zoom=15&maptype=road&style=feature%3Awater|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A17|&style=feature%3Alandscape|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xf5f5f5|lightness%3A20|&style=feature%3Aroad.highway|element%3Ageometry.fill|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A17|&style=feature%3Aroad.highway|element%3Ageometry.stroke|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A29|weight%3A0.2|&style=feature%3Aroad.arterial|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A18|&style=feature%3Aroad.local|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A16|&style=feature%3Apoi|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xf5f5f5|lightness%3A21|&style=feature%3Apoi.park|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A21|&style=feature%3Aall|element%3Alabels.text.stroke|visibility%3Aon|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A16|&style=feature%3Aall|element%3Alabels.text.fill|saturation%3A36|color%3A0x333333|lightness%3A40|&style=feature%3Aall|element%3Alabels.icon|visibility%3Aoff|&style=feature%3Atransit|element%3Ageometry|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A19|&style=feature%3Aadministrative|element%3Ageometry.fill|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A20|&style=feature%3Aadministrative|element%3Ageometry.stroke|color%3A0xffffff|lightness%3A17|weight%3A1.2|

Then use the z-index method to overlay you image (with transparency)
example http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/ontop.html

Mock up Example:
(needs refining)
http://jsfiddle.net/yUbV9/146/

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'm just going to give it a few days for other people to reply, and then I'll mark your post as the answer (so long as no one gives another one). Would you happen to know if I can query this with a lat/lng bounding box?

Comment: I took a closer look at this and realized that its not actually transparent at all. If I was to overlay this on top of my data (which is essentially a heatmap over the united states), the white in that static map would lighten the result image. What I want is to be able to place roads and labels over my basemap without distorting the basemap or lightening it.